# Scaling an Actor Application on Amazon Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-ec2, actor, akka

Beanstalk does the typical thing an autoscaling app would do: waits for demand (in the form of web requests) to spike, then it spawns new slaves for the cluster based on the registered AMI.

My question is, if I have an actor-based system, can I manually trigger the expansion of the grid? or do I have to route requests to my agents through some kind of http pipeline that AWS would recognize?

Seems like other solutions on AWS (e.g. **Hadoop**) allow for explicit control. Also, other solutions on top of AWS (e.g. **Heroku**) do as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I think an answer might be useful for those that come after. This looks like a case for AWS Autoscaling. See http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/autoscaling/.

Comment: But the question is whether there are provisions for scaling with actors.

Comment: I would probably create an AMI that contains the code for the slave that autostarts the application which joins the cluster, and set up the autoscaling group based for example on CPU usage. In the application, use a Cluster-Aware Router to create the worker actors on the new host. Not specifically for actors, but it should work.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I was hoping someone from either the Akka community or AWS arena would see the usefulness of this and build it. :)